# How much experience should a user have to use Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

As long as a question is clear and concise, can users of any level of experience ask questions? Or should only users of an intermediate and above level be allowed? What counts as too little or too inexperienced?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow btw, as this is a starting stack overflow type question; I quite like your first question but the one thing we hate is "noise", try not to put things like "(If I'm misusing this website, just tell me and I will go away)" or "beginning student" in your questions. If you feel the need to say such things (which there isn't really) put them in a comment

Comment: "noise" sounds like an accurate description. I can easily omit such things from posts. I must say that I'm surprised by the amount of response and professionalism here. I'm glad to be here.

Comment: Stack overflow is an amazing resource, a well written question can have an answer within 5 minutes

Answer (score 18):

The amount of experience you have isn't important, but let me make a few comments on your question.

1. You didn't need this at top of your question; don't include things unrelated to your question.

   `(If I'm misusing this website, just tell me and I will go away)`
2. A couple places you refer to `methods` but since you're not talking about any specific language it's hard for anyone to know how you want them to look. Do you have a standard in your class that defines how method definitions are supposed to be written?
3. You asked whether your teacher mistyped. No one here can answer that.
4. It sounds like you need Create and Print methods. It would have been helpful if you would have made an attempt to get started and post your best guess; no matter how bad it is. People love to get points and respond if they are sure what you're asking about.
5. There's already some really good posts about your topic. But it's not immediately obvious how to google for them: `design class book stackoverflow` doesn't return anything good. But this returns some good links `design class author title book stackoverflow`.

Comment: 1. I was a bit intimidated, I see how it is irrelevant. 2. & 4. I see how I should be a bit more specific. 3. That is true, I should have omitted that from my question. 5. I did attempt multiple searches, but they were a little basic, your recommendations helped. I'm still learning etiquette, but this puts me in the right direction. The website recommended not to say thanks, but thanks.

Comment: That was first my answer here, so I'm just learning to. Just jump in and be ready to learn from other people's feedback. Glad to help.

Comment: Congratulations on your first Answer, great analysis. I think 10 votes trigger a badge, do you like them? ;) @BasilErnst, thanks amidst a useful comment is cool, IMO, otherwise upvoting has the same meaning and triggers *points*, also known as *unicorn dollars*!

Answer (score 13):

Any level of question is accepable as long as you've tried something (often shown by including code where appropriate). What is important is that you have the experience to be able to form a good question and understand the answer. So to ask a basic question you only need to have basic knowledge. **However** most basic question have already been asked so search to avoid posting a duplicate

What tends to go badly is low experience users asking high experience questions with an implied "you'll have to do this for me"

Comment: how does the logo turtle fare under these criteria?

Comment: @JanDvorak Seemingly well; http://stackoverflow.com/tags/logo/info

Comment: @RichardTingle: That tag is being used for questions involving website logos, mostly..

Comment: @MartijnPieters And that’s definitely not why I linked to the tag page rather than recently asked. But still its existence suggests such questions are on topic

Comment: @RichardTingle this question is what I have in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo

Comment: @JanDvorak O god, and yet there is no "trying something"